# IE does not open a new window with the hash available after clicking on an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a link that would open up a new page when it is clicked, all works fine.. until i needed to use a  hash,#, for directing visitors to a certain part of the page.

All worked well with chrome, firefox and safari BUT when it came to IE, the hash portions are sliced of the from the redirection.

I know that hash are meant for client side scripts and would not be send to the server for considerations but i need to use it and i can't consider using anything else other than the hash.

*Yes, using queries,?, are totally out of the question here.*

Is there a workaround for the hash appear when redirected with an IE browser? such as a javascript window.open hack? i've tried some of it though, not working for me, might be missing something.

here is an example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZaZ7/)

PS* i'm using the Google site for the href as an example, any other sites are also okay. i just want to know if it's possible to open a new window when clicking on an anchor with the hash still on the address bar for IE's

Comment: `for directing visitors to a certain part of the page.` IE still scrolls to the anchor after redirect even without hash shown in the address bar.

Comment: This one worked for me in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/jZaZ7/2/ - when you say "redirected" do you mean a redirection done by the site you've linked to (such as what Google does)?

Comment: nnnnnnn, your jsfiddle has the results i wanted, that is when opening another page, the hash is still there. ermm sorry for the ambiguity in the redirect word, i meant to open another page in another window with the hash in the address bar like chrome or ff when clicking on an anchor. The Google site in fiddle was just an example i used, you can use any site for the testing. i'll update my title, it sounds wrong

Comment: This looks like some anomaly with Google and/or jsfiddle. I put a plain HTML example [here](http://www.strictquirks.nl/temp/caller.html) that doesn't remove the # with IE.

Comment: I've found the solution, it seems that on localhost there was a problem with IE opening a new window with the hash on it but as soon as i tried it with the contents online, the hash is there, not omitted by IE. Thanks for all your help guys

Comment: now, how do i close this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it seems that on localhost there was a problem with IE opening a new window with the hash on it but as soon as i tried it with the contents online, the hash is there, not omitted by IE